# unable to display json data in html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

i have this json data, i have crated two arrays and echoed it as json.
 and want to display it in html using two loops by matching id of one array and userId of another array.

```
{"personaldetails":[{"id":"79","FirstName":"Elon","MiddleName":"","LastName":"Musk","Gender":"Male","Location":"New York","Email":"elonmusk@tesla.com","Mobile":"1234567890"},{"id":"78","FirstName":"Elon","MiddleName":"","LastName":"Musk","Gender":"Male","Location":"New York","Email":"elonmusk@tesla.com","Mobile":"1234567890"},{"id":"77","FirstName":"Elon","MiddleName":"","LastName":"Musk","Gender":"Male","Location":"New York","Email":"elonmusk@tesla.com","Mobile":"1234567890"},{"id":"76","FirstName":"Elon","MiddleName":"","LastName":"Musk","Gender":"Male","Location":"New York","Email":"elonmusk@tesla.com","Mobile":"1234567890"},{"id":"75","FirstName":"Elon","MiddleName":"","LastName":"Musk","Gender":"Male","Location":"New York","Email":"elonmusk@tesla.com","Mobile":"1234567890"},{"id":"74","FirstName":"Elon","MiddleName":"","LastName":"Musk","Gender":"Male","Location":"New York","Email":"elonmusk@tesla.com","Mobile":"1234567890"},{"id":"73","FirstName":"Elon","MiddleName":"","LastName":"Musk","Gender":"Male","Location":"New York","Email":"elonmusk@tesla.com","Mobile":"1234567890"},{"id":"72","FirstName":"Elon","MiddleName":"","LastName":"Musk","Gender":"Male","Location":"New York","Email":"elonmusk@tesla.com","Mobile":"1234567890"},{"id":"71","FirstName":"Elon","MiddleName":"","LastName":"Musk","Gender":"Male","Location":"New York","Email":"elonmusk@tesla.com","Mobile":"1234567890"},{"id":"70","FirstName":"Elon","MiddleName":"","LastName":"Musk","Gender":"Male","Location":"New York","Email":"elonmusk@tesla.com","Mobile":"1234567890"},{"id":"69","FirstName":"Elon","MiddleName":"","LastName":"Musk","Gender":"Male","Location":"New York","Email":"elonmusk@tesla.com","Mobile":"1234567890"},{"id":"68","FirstName":"Elon","MiddleName":"","LastName":"Musk","Gender":"Male","Location":"New York","Email":"elonmusk@tesla.com","Mobile":"1234567890"}]}{"bookdetails":[{"UserId":"79","BookTitle":"who am i","BookGenre":"inspiration","BookWriter":"modi","BookDescription":"this book is all about the struggle one faces all his life.no matter what he does he never get any attention"},{"UserId":"79","BookTitle":"a walk to remember","BookGenre":"romance","BookWriter":"peter","BookDescription":"a wall in the rainy season where all "},{"UserId":"78","BookTitle":"who am i","BookGenre":"inspiration","BookWriter":"modi","BookDescription":"this book is all about the struggle one faces all his life.no matter what he does he never get any attention"},{"UserId":"78","BookTitle":"a walk to remember","BookGenre":"romance","BookWriter":"peter","BookDescription":"a wall in the rainy season where all "},{"UserId":"77","BookTitle":"who am i","BookGenre":"inspiration","BookWriter":"modi","BookDescription":"this book is all about the struggle one faces all his life.no matter what he does he never get any attention"},{"UserId":"77","BookTitle":"a walk to remember","BookGenre":"romance","BookWriter":"peter","BookDescription":"a wall in the rainy season where all "},{"UserId":"76","BookTitle":"who am i","BookGenre":"inspiration","BookWriter":"modi","BookDescription":"this book is all about the struggle one faces all his life.no matter what he does he never get any attention"},{"UserId":"76","BookTitle":"a walk to remember","BookGenre":"romance","BookWriter":"peter","BookDescription":"a wall in the rainy season where all "},{"UserId":"75","BookTitle":"who am i","BookGenre":"inspiration","BookWriter":"modi","BookDescription":"this book is all about the struggle one faces all his life.no matter what he does he never get any attention"},{"UserId":"75","BookTitle":"a walk to remember","BookGenre":"romance","BookWriter":"peter","BookDescription":"a wall in the rainy season where all "},{"UserId":"74","BookTitle":"who am i","BookGenre":"inspiration","BookWriter":"modi","BookDescription":"this book is all about the struggle one faces all his life.no matter what he does he never get any attention"},{"UserId":"74","BookTitle":"a walk to remember","BookGenre":"romance","BookWriter":"peter","BookDescription":"a wall in the rainy season where all "},{"UserId":"73","BookTitle":"who am i","BookGenre":"inspiration","BookWriter":"modi","BookDescription":"this book is all about the struggle one faces all his life.no matter what he does he never get any attention"},{"UserId":"73","BookTitle":"a walk
```

but i am not getting this data in html neither by console.log nor javascript alert.

here is code;

```
function loadData(){
    var url = "http://localhost/ReadExchange/api.php";
    $.getJSON(url,function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        alert("hey got the data"+JSON.stringify(data));
    });
}

$(function() {
    loadData();
});
```

here is my api code;

```
 $personal = $db->prepare('select Id,FirstName,MiddleName,LastName,Gender,Location,Email,Mobile from personaldetails ORDER BY Id DESC');
$personal->execute();
$json_data=array();



foreach($personal as $row)//foreach loop  
{  

    $json_array['id']=$row['Id'];  
    $json_array['FirstName']=$row['FirstName'];  
    $json_array['MiddleName']=$row['MiddleName'];  
    $json_array['LastName']=$row['LastName']; 
    $json_array['Gender']=$row['Gender']; 
    $json_array['Location']=$row['Location']; 
    $json_array['Email']=$row['Email']; 
    $json_array['Mobile']=$row['Mobile'];
    array_push($json_data,$json_array);
```

}

```
$books = $db->prepare('select UserId,BookTitle,BookGenre,BookWriter,BookDescription from bookdetails ORDER BY UserId Desc'); 
    $books->execute();
    $json_data1=array();

     //$bookNo = 0;
    foreach($books as $row)//foreach loop  
    {  
        //$bookNo++;
        //$json_array1['BookNo']= $bookNo;  
        $json_array1['UserId']=$row['UserId']; 
        $json_array1['BookTitle']=$row['BookTitle']; 
        $json_array1['BookGenre']=$row['BookGenre'];  
        $json_array1['BookWriter']=$row['BookWriter']; 
        $json_array1['BookDescription']=$row['BookDescription']; 

    //here pushing the values in to an array  
    array_push($json_data1,$json_array1);  

}  header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode(array("personaldetails"=>$json_data));
    echo json_encode(array("bookdetails"=>$json_data1));
    //echo json_encode($json_data1);  

?>
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to send only one JSON object, so not:

```
 echo json_encode(array("personaldetails"=>$json_data));
    echo json_encode(array("bookdetails"=>$json_data1));
```

But:

```
 echo json_encode(array(
       "personaldetails"=>$json_data,
       "bookdetails"=>$json_data1 
));
```

Comment: this is also working but still not getting any data in html

Comment: But this `console.log(data);` shows you this data in console after my fix? If not, check what exactly is returned by AJAX request